# Issue Looping through an array of Objects dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, object, for-loop

Working on a Laravel application whereby am fetching data from the frontend and populating
dynamically on the frontend using Javascript. On the frontend I have partitioned in 2 major columns (left column and right column). On the left column there is a link which when hovered over or clicked the respective policies display on the right side.

The problem is am finding it quite difficult to iterate the policies array which contains a collection of Javascript objects and display them dynamically in the table.

When I use the method below I get **[object Object]** in the table body

**asm variable from the backend**

```
"agency_sales": [
    {
        "id": "111",
        "policies": [
            {
                "name": "JOHN DOE 1",
                "sum_covered": "555000",
                "date": "2018-05-16 12:02:32"
            },
            {
                "name": "JOHN DOE 2",
                "sum_covered": "404000",
                "date": "2018-02-20 17:33:25"
            },
        ]
    }
    {
        "id": "222",
        "policies": [
            {
                "name": "JOHN DOE 1",
                "sum_covered": "555000",
                "date": "2018-05-16 12:02:32"
            },
            {
                "name": "JOHN DOE 2",
                "sum_covered": "404000",
                "date": "2018-02-20 17:33:25"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

**Left column containing the link with a dynamic id**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
@foreach($asm as $a)
     <a href="#demo{{$i}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" style="color: #868ba1;" id="{{ $a['id'] }}"> Agency Sales Managers ID : {{ $a['id'] }} </a>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**Right column containing the table I would like to populate dynamically**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 <table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-11" id="summary-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SUM</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Add policies dynamically via JS under respective thead columns--></tr> 
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var asmData = {!! json_encode($asm) !!};
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {

  //Make sure table is empty
  $('#summary-table tbody tr').html('');

  //Execute ASM
  var asmPolicies = '';
  //Fetch id of a tag in the DOM
  var asmId = $(this).attr('id');
  for(var i = 0; i < asmData.length; i++) {
      if(asmId == asmData[i]['id']) {
          for(var j = 0; j < asmData[i]['policies'].length; j++){
              asmPolicies += '<tr><td>' + asmData[i]['policies'][j] + '</td></tr>';
          }
      }

  }
  //append asmPolicies Html to the table
  $('#summary-table tbody tr').append(asmPolicies);
  //END ASM
});
```

Comment: Issue #1 as I see it is appending trs to one or more trs

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54071918/edit) then `[<>]` the snippet editor and since your question is about the front end, remove all references to the backend and post a [mcve] of the object and the jQuery only

Comment: While you're at it @Martin, can you also post sample data for `asmData`?

Comment: @jom asmData in a Js variable that holds the encoded data of the asm PHP variable..

Comment: @mplungjan Have used backend code to illustrate the array collection of JSON objects of policies that am trying to iterate individually and show each on the table under its respective thead column..

Comment: @jom,, am having an issue in the for loop in Js. Iterating through the policies array of objects and displaying each individually on the table under respective thead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues - the main ones are

- faulty JSON
- not parsing the object
- appending trs to trs instead of the tbody

Note the use of data attribute on the link

```js
const asmData = [{
  "id": "111",
  "policies": [{
      "name": "JOHN DOE 1",
      "sum_covered": "555000",
      "date": "2018-05-16 12:02:32"
    },
    {
      "name": "JOHN DOE 2",
      "sum_covered": "404000",
      "date": "2018-02-20 17:33:25"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "id": "222",
  "policies": [{
      "name": "JOHN DOE 3",
      "sum_covered": "555000",
      "date": "2018-05-16 12:02:32"
    },
    {
      "name": "JOHN DOE 4",
      "sum_covered": "404000",
      "date": "2018-02-20 17:33:25"
    }
  ]
}]



$(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {
  var $tb = $('#summary-table tbody');
  //Make sure table is empty

  $tb.empty()

  var asmId = $(this).attr('data-id'),
    asmPolicies = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < asmData.length; i++) {
    if (asmId == asmData[i]['id']) {
      for (var j = 0; j < asmData[i]['policies'].length; j++) {
        var pol = asmData[i]['policies'][j];
        asmPolicies += '<tr><td>' + pol.name + '</td><td>' + pol.sum_covered + '</td><td>' + pol.date + '</td><td>' + '</td></tr>';
      }
    }
  }
  //append asmPolicies Html to the table
  $tb.append(asmPolicies);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-id="111">111</a> | <a href="#" data-id="222">222</a>

<div class="col-md-8">
  <table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-11" id="summary-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>SUM</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- Add policies dynamically via JS under respective thead columns-->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works fine... Would like to add a functionality whereby when the **page loads I fetch all the data** and perform you logic on **mouse enter event**.. Did it but I keep getting the error asmData is not defined   **$( document ).ready(function() {
        var asmData = {!! json_encode($asm) !!};
    });**   and after mouse event ** $(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() { <!--Perform the logic -->} );
**